# Build a second admin section over Drupal 8

Tags: angular, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I'd like to develope a second admin panel (or section) on Drupal 8 completely separate from the existing one. I don't want to override the existing one, I clearly want two separates admin panel for two kinds of "administrator".
I think about develope it with a JS framework (like Angular2) and then use the Restful API provided by Drupal.

What should I do ? Should I create an admin module ? Or maybe doing it directly in the front theme ?
I'm not sure of what would be the better way to do it.

Comment: At its core, an Angular app is just a bunch of static files (js files, html templates...) exposed via a single page. How you generate that page in Drupal is entirely up to you. It could be a custom module, it could be a page in your theme... For encapsulation and ease of deployment, I would suggest wrapping your Angular app in a custom Drupal module, but there's no technical obligation to do so. A custom module will also let you easily define custom permissions for your admin panel #2, custom settings, etc.

Comment: I would use PHP and place my second custom back-end in some sub dir at site root and add Drupal's bootstrap at some php file that loads at start so Drupal functionality would be available to me in that custom back-end.